# How do I fix visible 'invisible-buttons' in Android app port to Blackberry?

Tags: android, android-widget, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

I have a very simple Android app. It is one Activity with Text and Buttons, and as you click on the buttons (onTouch events), they become invisible and the text changes.

This works fine for Android 3 and Android 2.3.3 simulators, but when I use the BlackBerry nature in Eclipse to send the app to a BlackBerry playbook simulator, funny things happen. As I click on the buttons they go invisible, but other buttons change too.

Buttons that were only ever visible, stay visible. Some Buttons that were invisible, become visible. Some buttons that had become visible earlier, return to being invisible.

It feels like a redraw problem, or some strange caching on the button state.

Anybody got any ideas? Wild guess excepted ...

Comment: How do you make your buttons invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Get a playbook or wait until RIM updates their broken simulator.

I converted an app for the playbook and the code was running fine on the simulator. It's a very simple app too, like a binary calculator. A couple of toggleButtons, Buttons and a TextView.
The app had visual issues, similar to yours. Buttons disappeared. Buttons were highlighted when I pressed buttons around them. ToggleButtons didn't change state. And much much more.

Since I don't have a playbook I couldn't test it on a real device. I tried layout changes, code changes and tried different settings. But nothing helped, those issues stayed.

After some reading in their forum I came to the conclusion that this might be an issue with the simulator.
So I submitted the app to the AppWorld 5 days ago. It got approved today.

So there is a chance that your app is alright, and the problem is the simulator.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping it was a simulator issue. My App went in 2 days ago :-)